# Angular Material - Hierarchical table

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

Does anyone have a sample for a heirarchical mat-table ?

The code in [Angular tables Examples](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) does have a detailed row. But I am looking for something with a parent child relation and lazy loading the details table on click of an expand button in the main table. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-z3pmzk

[MatTable Expand Collapse Icon issue on pagination and sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775715/mattable-expand-collapse-icon-issue-on-pagination-and-sort/53808807#53808807)